# Why print of awk failed to redirect?

Tags: linux, shell, redirect, awk, pipe

I need merge config file1 to config file2. If file 1 has file 2 does not, append it to end of file2. I can replace print with system for fix bug, but i don't know why print didn't work.

Use `print i"=" a[i] >> ARGV[2];` , failed to append text to  the end of text

1.txt，Notice that the 3rd line is a blank line:

```
key=5678
abc=000
```

2. txt:

```
key=1234
```

test.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S gawk -F= -f
{
    key = gensub(/\s/, "", "g", $1);
    if (NR==FNR) {
        a[key]=$2;
    } else {
        b[key]=$2;
    }
}

END{
    for (i in a) {
        if (b[i] == "") {
            print "bi = empty, append to end of file:" i"="a[i];
            print i"="a[i] >> ARGV[2];
            # system("echo " i "=" a[i] ">>" ARGV[2]);
        } else if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            cmd = sprintf("sed -i -r 's@\\s*(%s)\\s*=.*@\\1=%s@' %s", i, a[i], ARGV[2]);
            system(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

run ./test.awk 1.txt 2.txt
result ：

```
$ ./test.awk 1.txt 2.txt 
bi = empty, append to end of file:=
bi = empty, append to end of file:abc=000
$ cat 2.txt 
key=5678
=
```

Why is abc=000 not added to 2.txt? If it is changed to system ("echo" I "=" a [i] ">" argv [2]), and it is OK again, is there a bug in print?

In gnu awk manual, "5.9 Closing Input and Output Redirections", need call close function, when multiple commands operate on the same file，such as pipe or cmd，
it's too bad, so i give up print >>, only use system().

Finally, i use this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S gawk -F"=|is" -f
# File:   sync_kernelconfig.awk
# Author: Edward.Tang
# Mail:   edaplayer@163.com
# Function: 同步文件1的内核配置到文件2

function set_value(array, comment, k, v)
{
    if (!/^\s*#/) {
        array[k]=v;
    } else {
        comment[k]=$2;
    }
}

{
    key = gensub(/#|\s/, "", "g", $1);

    if (key == "") next; # 跳过空行

    if (NR==FNR) {
        set_value(a1, c1, key, $2);
    } else {
        set_value(a2, c2, key, $2);
        line[key] = $0; # line data of file2
    }
}

END {
    for (i in a1) {
        if (a2[i] == "") {
            if (c2[i] == "") {
                system("echo " i "=" a1[i] ">>" ARGV[2]);
            } else {
                cmd = sprintf("sed -i -r 's~%s~%s=%s~' %s", line[i], i, a1[i], ARGV[2]);
                system(cmd);
            }
        } else if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            cmd = sprintf("sed -i -r 's~%s~%s=%s~' %s", line[i], i, a1[i], ARGV[2]);
            system(cmd);
        }
    }

    for (i in c1) {
        if (a2[i] != "") {
            cmd = sprintf("sed -i -r 's~%s~# %s is%s~' %s", line[i], i, c1[i], ARGV[2]);
            system(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 注意第三行是个空行 mean? Can you translate it, please

Comment: Also it will be good to add what's the logic of your program along with sample of input and expected output too in your question for better understanding.

Comment: Try changing the END block to an ENDFILE block

Comment: @RamanSailopal After using  ENDFILE, result will becom
key=5678
=
key=5678
abc=000
=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gnu awk manual, "5.9 Closing Input and Output Redirections", need call close function, when multiple commands operate on the same file，such as pipe or cmd， it's too bad.

So i need use:

```
print i"="a[i] >> ARGV[2];
close(ARGV[2]);
```

or:

```
system("echo " i "=" a1[i] ">>" ARGV[2]);
```

Comment: Note that the `system()` version is both slower and deeply insecure -- if your data has `$(somecommand)` your shell will run that as code. And you can't just fix it by adding more quotes, because they can be countered by quotes in the data.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes，so i consider using perl now. It seems to can't do instant editing  with awk.

Comment: Restructuring your program to not be composed of in-place edits in the first place would be much better. Each such edit is rewriting your entire file; it's deeply inefficient.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you mean that record all items, then write once to file？I dont't have a better idea.